# Testing vue-filepond component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest, filepond

I have an "ImageUpload" component that uses [vue-filepond](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond) as the image uploader tool. I'm trying to test a function, `handleUpdateFiles`, that gets the file(s) from the `imageUploaderRef` ref and then emits that to parent components using `@vue/test-utils` and `vitest`.

Here is the component:

```
<template>
  <file-pond
    name="sc-image-uploader"
    ref="imageUploaderRef"
    :allow-multiple="allowMultiple"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    label-idle="Drag and drop or"
    :max-files="maxFiles"
    :files="files"
    :allow-file-encode="true"
    @updatefiles="handleUpdateFiles" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import vueFilePond from 'vue-filepond';
  import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
  import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css';

  import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type';
  import FilepondPluginImageValidateSize from 'filepond-plugin-image-validate-size';
  import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
  import FilePondPluginFileEncode from 'filepond-plugin-file-encode';

  const FilePond = vueFilePond(
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilepondPluginImageValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginFileEncode
  );

  defineProps({
    allowMultiple: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    maxFiles: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    }
  });

  const emit = defineEmits(['upload']);

  const imageUploaderRef = ref(null);
  const files = ref([]);
  const encodedFile = ref(null);

  function handleUpdateFiles () {
    const file = imageUploaderRef.value.getFile();
    encodedFile.value = file.getFileEncodeBase64String();
  }

  // watch for when encodedFile.value has a value, and emit when it does
  watch(encodedFile, (val) => {
    if (val) {
      emit('upload', val);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I can trigger `handleUpdateFiles` very easily, but the `imageUploaderRef.value` is undefined and does not have the `getFile` function that file-pond adds in. I've attempted various ways of stubbing that component and/or mock the `getFile` and `getFileEncodeBase64String` functions, but have yet to land anything that exposes `getFile` on `imageUploaderRef.value` in order to test that the `file` and `encodedFile` are being set correctly and the `upload` emit is being triggered.

Anyone run into similar issues testing with this library or have any spaghetti to throw at the wall?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this out with some vitest mocking:

```
it('handles file uploads and emits upload event', async () => {
    const testBase64EncodedFile = 'base64EncodedFile';
    const wrapper = mount(ImageUpload, {
      props,
    });

    const fileMock = {
      getFileEncodeBase64String: vi.fn()
        .mockReturnValue(testBase64EncodedFile),
    };

    wrapper.vm.imageUploaderRef = {
      getFile: vi.fn()
        .mockReturnValue(fileMock),
    };

    await wrapper.vm.handleUpdateFiles();

    expect(wrapper.vm.encodedFile)
      .toBe(testBase64EncodedFile);
    expect(wrapper.emitted('upload')[0][0])
      .toBe(testBase64EncodedFile);
  });
```